# how to set "stdout=true" while doing a webdeploy for asp.net core v3.1 app?

Tags: asp.net-core, stdout, webdeploy

I am publishing an asp.net core v3.1 app in visual studio 2019
since core apps do not create a `web.config`
webdeploy creates it and publishes its own web.config on every publish

while it does that 
it sets the `stdout=false` and i would like to be true - 
anyone know how to control this?
i was toying around with trying to configure something in the `.csproj`
but never found the correct combination

heres what the published web.config looks like:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myproj.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="false" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
```

and of course heres what i want it to look like:

```
<aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\myproj.dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess" />
```

another post about this same issue here:
https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/issues/31380

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can add a web.config to your poject by right click the project, add=>newItem=>Web=>Web Configuration File.And then you can set stdoutLogEnabled in it.

Example(pay attention you need to add `hostingModel="inprocess"`to web.config):

```
<system.webServer>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="aspNetCore"/>
      <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModule" resourceType="Unspecified"/>
    </handlers>
    <aspNetCore processPath="%LAUNCHER_PATH%" arguments="%LAUNCHER_ARGS%" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="InProcess"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

And here is the published web.config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <location path="." inheritInChildApplications="false">
    <system.webServer>
      <handlers>
        <add name="aspNetCore" path="*" verb="*" modules="AspNetCoreModuleV2" resourceType="Unspecified" />
      </handlers>
      <aspNetCore processPath="dotnet" arguments=".\case1(5-26).dll" stdoutLogEnabled="true" stdoutLogFile=".\logs\stdout" hostingModel="inprocess" />
    </system.webServer>
  </location>
</configuration>
```

Comment: so adding a web.config wont be detrimental to asp.net core serving process? i mean i just assumed (and from your answer - incorrectly so)  that since the build doesnt create it that it was implying that it was not good for serving up the app

Comment: web.config is the configuration of IIS,but the .net core does not only support IIS,so web.config is not created by the build.If you want to host on IIS,you can add a web.config to app.

Comment: I still cannot sort this out. The configuration is correct now, but log folder is not created. I have web application under Default Web site. I've tried to use MakeDir command within csproj file. I also tried to create the folder manually, but then I am getting weird error: `Could not start stdout file redirection to 'logs\stdout' with application base 'C:\inetpub\wwwroot\IdentityServer\'. ios_base::failbit set: iostream stream error`

Comment: @Alexander Do you have the leading dot in the file path `.\logs\stdout`?

Comment: just remember to set CopyToOutputDirectory on web.config file properties so it gets added to the publish...I always forget that setting